# attribute like colorAccent in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

In Android AppCompact Library we set theme for UI controls like checkboxes and text fields using `colorAccent` attribute. Like following images.

```
<item name="colorAccent">#43ffd6</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#ff6f4d</item>
```

[image]
[image]

Is there any attribute like this for Xamarin.Forms if I want this to effect in cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a thematic way of styling grouped elements in Xamarin.Forms then you can make use of Styles ([Xamarin.Forms Styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/)) e.g.

```
var buttonStyle = new Style (typeof(Button)) {
    Setters = {
        new Setter {Property = Button.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Color.Yellow},
        new Setter {Property = Button.BorderRadiusProperty, Value = 0},
        new Setter {Property = Button.HeightRequestProperty, Value = 42}
    }
}
// apply directly to a single control
var mybutton = new Button {
    Text = "Style Me",
    Style = buttonStyle
};
```

You can leverage this functionality to provide a themed style you can apply across multiple types of UI objects.

If styles are not your 'thing' (although I honestly can't see any reason not to use them) then you could subclass the UI object in question and create a new bindable object that could be responsible for setting the relevant properties.

Good luck

Comment: I would add on that you can still access the accents and set them in Android 20+ APIs and apply some material design. See: http://motzcod.es/post/115523285992/material-design-theming-for-xamarinforms-android